# favicon.ico won't show up in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, favicon

I have a 16x16 favicon.ico in app/assets/images. When I run

> rake assets:clean

and then

> rake assets:precompile

I can see that two fingerprinted files; `favicon.ico` and `favicon.ico.gz`, are generated in `public/assets`, as they should, because I am using the asset pipeline.

My `application.html.haml` contains this line, in the `%head` section:

```
= favicon_link_tag
```

However, no GET requests for `favicon.ico` appear in the terminal where

> rails server

is running. Also, no html for favicon appears on my page when I type 'Ctrl U' to view the page source.

I have tried to put `favicon.ico` in `public/img`, and to have it in both locations. I have tried various syntaxes for the line in `application.html.haml`, such as:

```
= favicon_link_tag "favicon.ico"

= favicon_link_tag "app/assets/images/favicon.ico"

%link{:href => "favicon.ico", :type => "image/x-icon"}
```

and so on. Flushing the browser cache is not relevant, since no GET request is made. I have deleted all favicons from the codebase, and put in new ones in various locations. What am I missing?

Comment: you have a typo `favicon_link_tog` instead of `favicon_link_tag`

Comment: I think you want this to be in the public folder.

Comment: @DeepakMahakale: thanks! edited.

Comment: @siegy22: as I mentioned, I have tried that too, although putting it in the public folder is for when you are _not_ using the asset pipeline.

Comment: None of the syntaxes you've tried produces any HTML output?

Comment: @memius I don't think that this is a good idea, I don't know if browsers will notify that this is the favicon if it has a cache key in it..

Comment: @Stefan: no, weirdly, I see no HTML output no matter what I've tried. I've tried with a couple of different .ico-files, in case there was something wrong with the file itself, but no luck.

Comment: If `%link` doesn't create a `<link>` tag, something is seriously broken and it is not caused by a missing favicon.

Comment: @siegy22: now that I got it working, the HTML for my page shows that the generated, fingerprinted favicon file from my asset pipeline is indeed being used. The original, unfingerprinted `favicon.ico` is in `app/assets/images`, to make it available for the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the people who were working on this rails app before me had added `landing.html.haml`, where I needed to put the `favicon_link_tag`. It had no effect in `application.html.haml`.

I also had to run

> rake assets:clobber

in order for the rails cache to be flushed, and the favicon.ico to get noticed.

I had been running

> rake assets:clean

which is for Rails 3, and doesn't do what I expect it to in Rails 4.